# How to use fontawesome with vue.js

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, elasticsearch-plugin

I was trying to use font-awesome with vue.js but couldn't got it running.

I tried including in the index but did not work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Include in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Now it should work